Can statistical significance testing methods be carried out on weighted data that was gathered using nonprobability-based sampling?
I am analyzing a survey dataset that was gathered using a nonprobability-based sampling method. This dataset also includes a weight field that may allow the survey results to be extrapolated to the broader population.
Given the presence of this weight data, would I be able to use traditional statistical significance testing methods like chi squared tests and t tests? (I would incorporate the weight values into my code using R's survey and srvyr packages or Python's samplics package. Or would those tests still be invalid because the original data was not gathered from a random sample? (If so, recommendations for alternative tests that are compatible with nonprobability-based sampling methods would be greatly appreciated.)

Could you explain how the extrapolation guarantee is justified?  In what sense is this a "nonprobability" sampling method?

There's no point in weighting the data unless you can (approximately) correct the sampling bias, and to the extent you can correct the sampling bias you can also do other forms of inference: you can get approximately correct standard errors, and see how many standard errors apart your estimates are, and so on.
This will all be quite sensitive to how good your reweighting is. The problem is more or less analogous to doing causal inference from observational data -- it's something that's done all the time, but it will never be fully reliable.
